# Changing the type of $router in Vue SFCs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-router, vetur

I've extended the router from `vue-router` with some custom properties. This works well at runtime, but I can't get typechecking to recognize the change in vscode for my Vue SFC files.

My `vue-shims.d.ts` looks like this:

```js
import type { User } from '../common/api'
import type { CustomRouter } from './router'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $user: User
    $router: CustomRouter
  }
}
```

Other declarations are correctly set, e.g. `$user` has the correct type. However, `$router` is still always type `VueRouter`. How can I make it prioritize my declaration over the library one?

Comment: Does this work specifically when you run `build`?

Comment: If I disable `transpileOnly` and run a production webpack build, I get the same typescript errors, yep. (so it's not just an editor problem)

Comment: Have you imported router instead of your custom router in any other modules?

Comment: The only import reference to `vue-router` I have is in `router.ts`, where I define my CustomRouter as `class CustomRouter extends Router`

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this-- I ended up just renaming my custom $router to $routing to avoid the conflict